# Keyboard is coming very slowly in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have an app with a TextField. If TextField is empty then it is displayed `UIAlertView` with one button. When a user taps on a button in `UIAlertView`, he must return to the TextField.

I'm using `self.TextField.becomeFirstResponder()` for this. It works. But the problem is that the keyboard is displayed really slowly. It looks like there is a one second delay before displayed.

```
     if TextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true {

     let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Text", preferredStyle: .alert)
     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

     self.TextField.becomeFirstResponder()
     }))

     self.present(alert, animated: true)
     print("textField is empty")

     } else { ...
```

Comment: Show some code of how you called `becomeFirstResponder`. Also note that sometimes a little delay is normal. The keyboard can't be show while your `UIAlertController` is in the way.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The part of code is added to the post.

Comment: I have a one second delay, even when I set a self.present animated to false.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `Slow Animation` is disabled in `Debug` menu:

[image]